Video + Audio+Youtube Player
I'm looking for a comprehensive package that includes audio, video, and YouTube player functionality from the cloud(not local).
This package should be compatible with Android, iOS, and web platforms, and it should support event handling such as play, pause, and other controls.
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.2.0
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 8.2.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 18.2.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 18.2.1
   @angular/cli                  : 18.2.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 11.0.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 6.1.2
   @capacitor/android : 6.1.2
   @capacitor/core    : 6.1.2
   @capacitor/ios     : 6.1.2

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : 2.0.1

System:

   NodeJS : v18.20.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 10.7.0

I've tested :
HTML5 audio and video
plyr + ngx-plyr (not supported and cant be used by my versions)
Could you please recommend some stable plugin with audio, video, and YouTube player functionality?
